# Postback from client-generated links (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have AJAX functionality on my page which creates anchor tags. I know I can fabricate a postback for these links by setting the href attribute to `javascript:__doPostBack('ControlID','SomeArgument')`

How do I execute server code based on this fake postback for 'controls' that are created on the client side?

Comment: Do you really need "fake postbacks", why not create AJAX calls to a WCF/ASMX/Page Method to perform your work server side.

Comment: The postback event will update attributes in a custom server control on the page, which will then re-bind. Unfortunately this can't be done with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **[IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx)** on your page.

Comment: Doesn't System.Web.UI.Page already implement that interface? It has a virtual method for RaisePostBackEvent anyway...

Comment: @Rob - then override it - sorry, haven't done any WebForms development in over a year ;-)

Comment: When using javascript:__doPostBack('CustomLink','test') RaisePostBackEvent is never called on the Page. Presumably the control must pre-exsit. I've tried to create a blank link button & hijack the ID but this results in postback validation errors